# Hotcakes Current Order Listing

Tags: e-commerce

We have hotcakes as our ecommerce backend of our website.  I need to pull down existing open orders either by date or non-shipped (for this option, I would need the ability to update orders that are currently in the system to a shipped/closed status) as all orders we received since the website launch are still showing as open orders.

I did find several API examples on the hotcakes website, and found the same issue as another user in that every order in the database gets downloaded.  I see you can download a specific order by it's ID number, but this is not useful currently as I don't know which orders numbers are open and not shipped.

If you can point me in the right direction to getting this accomplished, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've been looking through the REST API examples for searching orders.  While the REST API is useful and quick to build upon, some things are better built using the server-side API.  This is one of those cases.  Here's an example code snippet that uses the search part of the orders API to retrieve a subset of the orders, instead of all of them.  If you use Visual Studio, it will also give you intellisense to determine all of the ways you might want to use the available search criteria.

If you're using Hotcakes 01.10.xx:

```
var HccApp = HccAppHelper.InitHccApp();

var searchCriteria = new OrderSearchCriteria
{
    StartDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7),
    EndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
};

var totalResults = 0;
var ordersByDateRange = HccApp.OrderServices.Orders.FindByCriteriaPaged(searchCriteria, 1, 10, ref totalResults);

// now do something with the orders
```

If you're using Hotcakes 02.xx:

```
var context = HccRequestContext.Current;

var searchCriteria = new OrderSearchCriteria
{
    StartDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7),
    EndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
};

var totalResults = 0;
var ordersByDateRange = Factory.CreateService<OrderService>(context).Orders.FindByCriteriaPaged(searchCriteria, 1, 10, ref totalResults);

// now do something with the orders
```

The code snippets above would of course require that you have or get a web context in order for them to be completely useful.